# How to combine two variables in linear multiple regression

Tags: r, self-study, multiple-regression, multicollinearity

I have LRM with two variables related to education level: one is responsible of higher school graduation (binary, 1 or 0), another one represents the number of years spent on education (discrete, not categorical, from 1 to ...).

Consequently, these two variables are highly correlated in the model inference.

**Question**: Can I incorporate the coefficients (i.e., estimates) of these two variables and then analyse how the education level is associated with, as in my LRM, life satisfaction? If so, how can I implement it? Are there any techniques which respectively work in R? Please, write your response in detail.

**UPD:**

Can I just use two estimates and creates from them a new variable? For example, these two variables are related to education, one is discrete and numeric, another is categorical. Having estimates coefficients, can I incorporate them in this way?

`nids$educ <- 0.076461*nids$education + 0.183*nids$hsgrad`

I tested it by Kappa it shows that I have even more troubles with model when I incorporate these two variables.

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042117/screening-multicollinearity-in-a-regression-model

Comment: This is good but mostly useless now. There are only responses on increasing the troubles :)